Behavior of std::move with push_back vs emplace_back
Assuming the following snippets compile and run.
I don't see an obvious difference between this:
v.push_back(std::move(a)) 

and this:
v.emplace_back(std::move(a))

Both seem to avoid creating a copy. If that is the case, I can always write:
class A { ... };

void func() {
  std::vector<A> v;
  A a;
  FillA(&a);
  v.push_back(std::move(a))  // I don't see any benefit using v.emplace_back(std::move(a))
}


If you start with an existing A object and move it, then there is very little difference between push_back and emplace_back. They both will construct a new element and move the source object into it. To avoid that extra source object, you can get rid of the local A variable and just fill an emplace'd element instead, letting emplace_back() default-construct the A object for you, eg: v.emplace_back(); FillA(&v.back()); Or in C++17 and later: FillA(&v.emplace_back());
